# Actuator Exposing Endpoints not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am using **spring boot 2.0.4** and want to expose my actuator endpoints. When adding the following to **application.yml** only **info, health** are being exposed.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

When I run http://localhost:8080/actuator I get

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator","templated":false},"health":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/health","templated":false},"info":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/info","templated":false}}}
```

Comment: did you try shutdown and restart your application ?

Comment: Yes multiple times, I'm running this in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.0 takes a slightly different approach to ensure web endpoints security. The majority of Web endpoints are now disabled by default (Only the /health and /info endpoints are exposed) and the management.security.enabled property has been removed. There is no longer a separate security auto-configuration for the Actuator, individual endpoints may be enabled/disabled and/or exposed via configuration in the application.properties file. For example:

```
# disable beans endpoint  
management.endpoints.beans.enabled=false  
# expose all endpoints:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

See additional info Spring official documentation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#endpoints

Comment: I read all the documentation and followed them closely. Even added a PermitAll to web security.

Comment: I added management.endpoints.beans.enabled=true, and still beans doesn't show.

Comment: Even tried disable beans endpoint  
management.endpoints.beans.enabled=false  
# expose all endpoints:
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bean ( or "bean")

Comment: Could you upload the project to  GitHub to be able to verify cofiguration?

Comment: Actually, I reimported the project, and followed you example and it worked. Not sure what was going on in my old project.

Comment: Perhaps your IDE did not refresh your project when you tried to start your boot module. I am glad to hear that it worked like a charm!!!!!!